# getting pixel's palette from BMP using PHP GD library

Tags: php, gd, bmp

I'm trying to catch information from BMP file, more precisely speaking I want to get RGB palette values of each pixel and output them, something like this
r->100 g->48 b->75...
As I understand PHP GD has no function for BMP format like imagecreatefromjpeg(), therefore I have found some scripts from internet which do the same with BMP...
In case of jpeg I can do this

```
  $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
  $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
  $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
  $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
```

but to get the $r value what should I write for BMP instead of ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;

---

and here is that function

```
function imageCreateFromBMP($filename)
{
    //Ouverture du fichier en mode binaire
    if (! $f1 = fopen($filename,"rb")) return FALSE;

    //1 : Chargement des ent?tes FICHIER
    $FILE = unpack("vfile_type/Vfile_size/Vreserved/Vbitmap_offset", fread($f1,14));
    if ($FILE['file_type'] != 19778) return FALSE;

    //2 : Chargement des ent?tes BMP
    $BMP = unpack('Vheader_size/Vwidth/Vheight/vplanes/vbits_per_pixel'.
                 '/Vcompression/Vsize_bitmap/Vhoriz_resolution'.
                 '/Vvert_resolution/Vcolors_used/Vcolors_important', fread($f1,40));
    $BMP['colors'] = pow(2,$BMP['bits_per_pixel']);
    if ($BMP['size_bitmap'] == 0) $BMP['size_bitmap'] = $FILE['file_size'] - $FILE['bitmap_offset'];
    $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'] = $BMP['bits_per_pixel']/8;
    $BMP['bytes_per_pixel2'] = ceil($BMP['bytes_per_pixel']);
    $BMP['decal'] = ($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
    $BMP['decal'] -= floor($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
    $BMP['decal'] = 4-(4*$BMP['decal']);
    if ($BMP['decal'] == 4) $BMP['decal'] = 0;

    //3 : Chargement des couleurs de la palette
    $PALETTE = array();
    if ($BMP['colors'] < 16777216)
    {
        $PALETTE = unpack('V'.$BMP['colors'], fread($f1,$BMP['colors']*4));
    }

    //4 : Cr?ation de l'image
    $IMG = fread($f1,$BMP['size_bitmap']);
    $VIDE = chr(0);

    $res = imagecreatetruecolor($BMP['width'],$BMP['height']);
    $P = 0;
    $Y = $BMP['height']-1;
    while ($Y >= 0)
    {
    $X=0;
    while ($X < $BMP['width'])
    {
    if ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 24)
        $COLOR = unpack("V",substr($IMG,$P,3).$VIDE);
    elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 16)
    {  
        $COLOR = unpack("n",substr($IMG,$P,2));
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
    }
    elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 8)
    {  
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,$P,1));
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
    }
    elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 4)
    {
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
        if (($P*2)%2 == 0) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] >> 4) ; else $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x0F);
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
    }
    elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 1)
    {
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
        if     (($P*8)%8 == 0) $COLOR[1] =  $COLOR[1]        >>7;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 1) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x40)>>6;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 2) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x20)>>5;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 3) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x10)>>4;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 4) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x8)>>3;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 5) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x4)>>2;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 6) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x2)>>1;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 7) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x1);
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
        imagesetpixel($res,$X,$Y,$COLOR[1]);
        $X++;
        $P += $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'];
    }
    $Y--;
    $P+=$BMP['decal'];
    }

    //Fermeture du fichier
    fclose($f1);

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what do these "scripts from internet" do? Do they convert the bmp into something GD can load? Do they implement their own gd-like api? Without any details of how you're loading this bmp, and what it's internal in-memory representation will be, this question can't be answered.

Comment: hi, I have edited the question and added the function you've requested

Comment: but it is not necessary to use exactly that function, if you know better ways for finding the values of pixels share pls, I just need to get that array of values

Answer (score 0):

This is a user contributed notes and code snippet of imagecreatefrombmp function in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) website which I think it would be useful for you.

```
<?php
/*********************************************/
/* Fonction: ImageCreateFromBMP              */
/* Author:   DHKold                          */
/* Contact:  admin@dhkold.com                */
/* Date:     The 15th of June 2005           */
/* Version:  2.0B                            */
/*********************************************/

function ImageCreateFromBMP($filename)
{
 //Ouverture du fichier en mode binaire
   if (! $f1 = fopen($filename,"rb")) return FALSE;

 //1 : Chargement des ent�tes FICHIER
   $FILE = unpack("vfile_type/Vfile_size/Vreserved/Vbitmap_offset", fread($f1,14));
   if ($FILE['file_type'] != 19778) return FALSE;

 //2 : Chargement des ent�tes BMP
   $BMP = unpack('Vheader_size/Vwidth/Vheight/vplanes/vbits_per_pixel'.
                 '/Vcompression/Vsize_bitmap/Vhoriz_resolution'.
                 '/Vvert_resolution/Vcolors_used/Vcolors_important', fread($f1,40));
   $BMP['colors'] = pow(2,$BMP['bits_per_pixel']);
   if ($BMP['size_bitmap'] == 0) $BMP['size_bitmap'] = $FILE['file_size'] - $FILE['bitmap_offset'];
   $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'] = $BMP['bits_per_pixel']/8;
   $BMP['bytes_per_pixel2'] = ceil($BMP['bytes_per_pixel']);
   $BMP['decal'] = ($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
   $BMP['decal'] -= floor($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
   $BMP['decal'] = 4-(4*$BMP['decal']);
   if ($BMP['decal'] == 4) $BMP['decal'] = 0;

 //3 : Chargement des couleurs de la palette
   $PALETTE = array();
   if ($BMP['colors'] < 16777216)
   {
    $PALETTE = unpack('V'.$BMP['colors'], fread($f1,$BMP['colors']*4));
   }

 //4 : Cr�ation de l'image
   $IMG = fread($f1,$BMP['size_bitmap']);
   $VIDE = chr(0);

   $res = imagecreatetruecolor($BMP['width'],$BMP['height']);
   $P = 0;
   $Y = $BMP['height']-1;
   while ($Y >= 0)
   {
    $X=0;
    while ($X < $BMP['width'])
    {
     if ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 24)
        $COLOR = unpack("V",substr($IMG,$P,3).$VIDE);
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 16)
     { 
        $COLOR = unpack("n",substr($IMG,$P,2));
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 8)
     { 
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,$P,1));
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 4)
     {
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
        if (($P*2)%2 == 0) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] >> 4) ; else $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x0F);
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 1)
     {
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
        if     (($P*8)%8 == 0) $COLOR[1] =  $COLOR[1]        >>7;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 1) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x40)>>6;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 2) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x20)>>5;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 3) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x10)>>4;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 4) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x8)>>3;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 5) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x4)>>2;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 6) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x2)>>1;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 7) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x1);
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     else
        return FALSE;
     imagesetpixel($res,$X,$Y,$COLOR[1]);
     $X++;
     $P += $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'];
    }
    $Y--;
    $P+=$BMP['decal'];
   }

 //Fermeture du fichier
   fclose($f1);

 return $res;
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I saw it before, did a lot of researches, still cannot find the answer. the question is what to write instead of 
  $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
  $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
  $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
to get the right values (r=0-255) of pixel, let's say in case of 8 bit BMP file